# Hey guys i'm facing some type of weird error while installing this package @truffle\hdwallet-provider

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

hey there everyone i'm making a Social media smart contract while installing other packages it works fine while i'm trying to truffle/hdwallet-provider i'm facing this issue hope you understand it
[please check this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnfSI.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This package has been renamed to

> @truffle/hdwallet-provider

You're using npm i truffle/hdwallet-provider

All you need is git installed in your PC

If installed type this command in cmd git --version.

If it returns any version you are good. Otherwise:

go to system environment variables settings-> System variables-> Path-> paste your git path Your git path -> C->program files->git->bin->click on address bar on top and copy the path and then paste in above process

Now apply the settings and then restart your PC.

Now open cmd and type git--version

Comment: thanks a lot man i wish i could hug you thanks for recommending for git God bless you